# Add a table after appendix title in two-columns document

Tags: tables, positioning, two-column, appendices

I'm trying to add a table***** to my two-column document as an appendix. However, the table is always displayed in a new page, even though I have other tables and figures in the body of my document which do not produce page breaks (the table I want to add to appendices used to be in the body).

Does anyone know where this problem comes from and how to bring my table under the appendix title? The size of table doesn't seem to be issue since it is small in the example and it is still displayed in a new page.

### SSCCE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
Some text...

\clearpage
\appendix
\appendixpage

\section*{My Appendix}

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Chapter & Section & A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}*{Chapter 1} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{Chapter 2} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image: SSCCE result]

Comment: Have You rtied just table, not table*?

Comment: `table*` spans two columns so it can not come under a section heading, you can only span at the top of a page

Comment: perhaps you want `\onecolumn` before the section heading then use `\begin{table}[htp]` to allow the table to be mid-page

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about this interaction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spannning table can not appear mid-page so not under a section heading.

However you can have a one-column appendix with an `[h]` table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
Some text...

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\appendix
\appendixpage

\section*{My Appendix}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Chapter & Section & A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}*{Chapter 1} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{Chapter 2} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue two column text after the table, you can use `\twocolumn[...]`.  However, you can't use `table` there, but you can use `\captionof{table}{...}`(if you had a caption).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
Some text...

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\appendix
\appendixpage
\twocolumn[\section*{My Appendix}

\vskip\intextsep
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Chapter & Section & A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}*{Chapter 1} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{Chapter 2} & Section 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Section 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\par\vskip\intextsep]

Now continue text in two columns.

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```